# Selected vertices in editmode are invisible in objectmode

Tags: vertices, visibility, select

When selecting vertices in edit mode, the objects verticies become invisible in object mode.

[image]

[image: Invisible Object]

When selecting only a face it gets invisible too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you create a New file, does it do the same thing ? Or is it only in a specific .blend ?

Comment: Vertices are supposed to become invisible or let's say unavailable in object mode though. So the first pictures show how it's supposed to be. A selected face be it selected by the vertices around it(Vertex Mode), the edges building it (Edge Mode) or just the face (Face mode) is a different story and should be checked as @thibsert mentioned. Also important, what version of Blender you are running.